# What's the easiest way to find out the number of files in a directory of folders?

Tags: batch-file

Is this easily achievable with MS-DOS scripts, or would I have to resort to C++, Python, Perl, or other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Wow! Are you really using MS-DOS? Didn't think that is still alive...

Comment: What I really meant was whatever easiest way to achieve this when using Windows 7

Comment: the dir-command reports the number of files/folders

Comment: @Fredrik: it only tells you the number of files in the current directory, it doesn't include the files in subdirectories (unless there is some switch I don't know about--DOS is not my strongest suit!)

Comment: dir /s is recursive and reports the total number of files/folders

Comment: Stanigator, great avatar, are you a fellow Detroiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be easiest, it has to pass the "my grandmother can do it" benchmark.

After thorough  benchmarking, I determined that the easiest approach would be to open each folder in windows explorer, look at the file count in the status bar, and use a calculator to add the counts.

It is slow, but effective.

**EDIT**

It might not be as easy, but as a heavy cygwin user, I tend to use the find command and wc.

```
find -type 'f' | wc -l
```

Comment: I meant easiest way but faster than opening each folder in windows explorer.

Comment: @stanigator, you took me way too seriously.

Answer (score 1):

in cmd you can do:

```
set i=0
for /f %%G in ('dir /b /A-d <dirname>') do set /a i=i+1
```

in PowerShell (which is available by default in Windows 7) you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem <dirname> | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Measure-Object
```

These commands count only files if you want to count directories as well remove `/A-d` for the dos version and `Where-Object { -not $_PSIsContainer }` for the powershell command. If you want to recurse into the subdirectories use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` in powershell or add a `/s` switch to the dir command in the dos version

Comment: And if you want a count of the files in subdirectories as well, add the `/s` switch to give you `'dir /b /A-d /s <dirname>'`

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward in python:

```
import os

walker = os.walk(path_to_search_root)
files = 0

for dir in walker:
    files += len(dir[2]) #dir[2] is the list of files in the directory

print files
```